# How can I open a fragment in a RecyclerView.Adapter to let User go to other users profile

Tags: java, android-studio

Good day everyone,

I am setting up a social media kinda app. In my "UserAdapter.java"

The user can chat with other users by tapping longer on the user_item. The chat function work without any problems. I am using "setOnLongClickListener" for this. The idea is, that the user can choose, wether he wants to chat by longer clicking or single tab to visit their profile but visiting their profile results in a crash. I want to make it something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ChatActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("hisUid", hisUid);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

This is what I use for the Chatfunction with ChatActivity. Fragments are still kinda new to me, so I don't know how to deal with them. I tried with the same code as in my MainActivity:

PersonProfileFragment is the other Users Profile Fragment.

```
PersonProfileFragment personProfileFragment = new PersonProfileFragment();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, personProfileFragment, "");
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Sadly an error show with: Cannot find symbol method "getSupportFragmentManager"

So what can I do to allow the user to visit the other users profile?

I've been looking around on Stackoverflow for some solutions but nothing worked yet.

public class UserAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
private Context context;
private List<User> userList;

// Constructor
public UserAdapter(Context context, List<User> userList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.userList = userList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    // Inflate layout (row_user.xml)
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.user_item, viewGroup, false);
    return new MyHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyHolder myHolder, final int i) {

    // Get data
    final String hisUid = userList.get(i).getUid();
    String userImage = userList.get(i).getImage();
    String userName = userList.get(i).getUsername();
    final String userFullname = userList.get(i).getFullname();

    // Set data
    myHolder.mNameTv.setText(userName);
    myHolder.mFullnameTv.setText(userFullname);

    try {
        Picasso.get().load(userImage)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.profile)
                .into(myHolder.mAvatarIv);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    // Handle item click: Get signed in User to ChatActivity to chat with other User
    myHolder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

            /* Click user from user list to start chatting/messaging. Start activity
               by putting UID of receiver. We will use that UID to identify the user
               we are going to chat with
             */

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ChatActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("hisUid", hisUid);
            context.startActivity(intent);

            return true;
        }
    });

    // Handle item click: Get signed in User to other User's profile
    myHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


        }
    });
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return userList.size();
}

// View Holder class
class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private ImageView mAvatarIv;
    private TextView mNameTv, mFullnameTv;

    public MyHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        // Init views
        mAvatarIv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.avatarIv);
        mNameTv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.username_userItem);
        mFullnameTv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.fullname_userItem);
    }

}
```

}

I'll provide any code, that is need, if this isn't enough.

I've tried:

```
 private boolean isFragment; 

public UserAdapter(Context context, List<User> userList, boolean isFragment) {
        this.context = context;
        this.userList = userList;
        this.isFragment = isFragment;
    }

// Handle item click: Get signed in User to other User's profile
    myHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (isFragment) {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences("SP_USER", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putString("hisUid", hisUid);
                editor.apply();

                ((FragmentActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,
                        new PersonProfileFragment()).commit();
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, DashboardActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("hisUid", hisUid);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }

        }
    });
}
```

But it gives me an Error: error: constructor UserAdapter in class UserAdapter. Required: Context, List, boolean. found: FragmentActivity, List

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getSupportFragmentManager` is activity's method, so you need to pass your activity to the recycler_view adapter and call: `mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager()` to get fragment manager.

Comment: Thank you very much. I still have a question, though. How can I solve the:

error: constructor UserAdapter in class UserAdapter. Required: Context, List, boolean. found: FragmentActivity, List ?